# Jenkins pipeline not triggered by Bitbucket Server push/PR, but freestyle project does

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

I'm working on configuring a Jenkins setup where a pipeline should be triggered every time there's a push or pull request made on a Bitbucket Server repository. Interestingly, this setup works seamlessly for freestyle projects, but it doesn't seem to activate for pipeline projects.

Here's my configuration:

- **Jenkins version: 2.427**
- **Bitbucket Server: 8.14.1**

Plugins:

- **Bitbucket Push and Pull Request: 2.8.4**
- **Git plugin: 5.2.0**

In my configuration, the only option I've selected is shown in this [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/w5BVTKx.png). For source code management (SCM), I'm using Git. When I test the connection, I receive the following message:

Jenkins successfully connected to bitbucket-managed's jenkins/sample on Primary Server

The webhook on the Bitbucket side is also set up correctly, and I've confirmed it returns a 200 OK status when hitting a custom endpoint.

However, here's the anomaly: when I try to merge changes from the staging branch to the master branch, it triggers a freestyle project but not the pipeline project.

Here's what I found in Jenkins logs so far

[image]

As you can see, the webhook itself did trigger
[image]

Bitbucket Logs

```
2023-10-11 08:08:08,438 DEBUG [http-nio-7990-exec-5] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.p.InternalPullRequestCommitHelper Indexing: linking PR 3070 with 26 commit(s) using include: 6c880405f0d63e97b54d3ce080bba38383618e03
2023-10-11 08:08:08,484 DEBUG [http-nio-7990-exec-5] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.e.TransactionAwareEventPublisher Deferring publishing for WatcherAddedEvent until AFTER_COMMIT
2023-10-11 08:08:08,484 DEBUG [http-nio-7990-exec-5] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.e.TransactionAwareEventPublisher Deferring publishing for PullRequestActivityEvent until AFTER_COMMIT
2023-10-11 08:08:08,484 DEBUG [http-nio-7990-exec-5] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.e.TransactionAwareEventPublisher Deferring publishing for AnalyticsPullRequestOpenedEvent until AFTER_COMMIT
2023-10-11 08:08:08,532 DEBUG [http-nio-7990-exec-5] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.e.TransactionAwareEventPublisher Publishing WatcherAddedEvent after commit
2023-10-11 08:08:08,532 DEBUG [http-nio-7990-exec-5] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.e.TransactionAwareEventPublisher Publishing PullRequestActivityEvent after commit
2023-10-11 08:08:08,532 DEBUG [http-nio-7990-exec-5] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.e.TransactionAwareEventPublisher Publishing AnalyticsPullRequestOpenedEvent after commit
2023-10-11 08:08:08,533 DEBUG [threadpool:thread-2] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.n.DefaultNotificationManager Managing notification: PullRequestActivityNotification{admin=InternalNormaladmin{id=753, adminname=admin}, timestamp=Wed Oct 11 08:08:08 IDT 2023, pullRequest=jenkins:9, activity=InternalPullRequestActivity{id=66284, admin=InternalNormaladmin{id=753, adminname=admin}, action=OPENED, pullRequest.id=9}}
2023-10-11 08:08:08,533 DEBUG [AtlassianEvent::thread-3] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" c.a.e.r.impl.RemoteEventListener Queueing RemoteEvent com.atlassian.stash.plugin.remote.event.StashPullRequestOpenedRemoteEvent@c9decd7[fromBranch=refs/heads/main,fromProjectKey=JENKINS,fromRepositorySlug=jenkins,id=9,toBranch=refs/heads/master,toProjectKey=JENKINS,toRepositorySlug=jenkins,sourceId=<null>,sourceUrl=<null>]
2023-10-11 08:08:08,533 DEBUG [threadpool:thread-1] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.n.DefaultNotificationManager Managing notification: PullRequestOpenedNotification{admin=InternalNormaladmin{id=753, adminname=admin}, timestamp=Wed Oct 11 08:08:08 IDT 2023, pullRequest=jenkins:9}
2023-10-11 08:08:08,534 DEBUG [AtlassianEvent::thread-3] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" c.a.e.r.impl.RemoteEventDispatcher RemoteEvent com.atlassian.stash.plugin.remote.event.StashPullRequestOpenedRemoteEvent@c9decd7[fromBranch=refs/heads/main,fromProjectKey=JENKINS,fromRepositorySlug=jenkins,id=9,toBranch=refs/heads/master,toProjectKey=JENKINS,toRepositorySlug=jenkins,sourceId=<null>,sourceUrl=<null>] consumable by []
2023-10-11 08:08:08,534 DEBUG [AtlassianEvent::thread-3] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" c.a.e.r.impl.RemoteEventListener Batch size not exceeded for com.atlassian.stash.plugin.remote.event.StashPullRequestOpenedRemoteEvent@c9decd7[fromBranch=refs/heads/main,fromProjectKey=JENKINS,fromRepositorySlug=jenkins,id=9,toBranch=refs/heads/master,toProjectKey=JENKINS,toRepositorySlug=jenkins,sourceId=<null>,sourceUrl=<null>]
2023-10-11 08:08:08,534 INFO  [moveworkforward-bitbucket-1] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" c.m.b.listener.AbstractEventListener Creating Event for: com.atlassian.stash.internal.pull.AnalyticsPullRequestOpenedEvent[source=com.atlassian.stash.internal.pull.DefaultPullRequestService@2bad091d]
2023-10-11 08:08:08,535 INFO  [moveworkforward-bitbucket-1] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" n.t.bitbucket.service.LicenseManager Plugin licensed.
2023-10-11 08:08:08,535 INFO  [moveworkforward-bitbucket-1] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" n.t.b.processor.AbstractProcessor isEventAccepted for event type: PULL_REQUEST_OPENED, and result is true, class : PullRequestProcessor
2023-10-11 08:08:08,535 INFO  [moveworkforward-bitbucket-1] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" n.t.b.processor.PullRequestProcessor isEventAccepted for event type: PULL_REQUEST_OPENED
2023-10-11 08:08:08,535 INFO  [moveworkforward-bitbucket-1] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" n.t.b.processor.PullRequestProcessor isEventAccepted result: true
2023-10-11 08:08:08,535 INFO  [moveworkforward-bitbucket-1] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" c.m.b.listener.AbstractEventListener nl.topicus.bitbucket.processor.PullRequestProcessor accepted event by type: PULL_REQUEST_OPENED
2023-10-11 08:08:08,535 INFO  [moveworkforward-bitbucket-1] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" n.t.b.processor.PullRequestProcessor Processing event with type: PULL_REQUEST_OPENED
2023-10-11 08:08:08,535 INFO  [moveworkforward-bitbucket-1] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" n.t.b.processor.PullRequestProcessor sendPullRequestEvent: PULL_REQUEST_OPENED
2023-10-11 08:08:08,614 DEBUG [moveworkforward-bitbucket-1] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.s.g.m.MeshPullRequestRefHelper JENKINS/jenkins[203]: Pull request 9@0 merged automatically without conflicts
2023-10-11 08:08:08,627 INFO  [moveworkforward-bitbucket-1] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" n.t.b.processor.PullRequestProcessor sendPullRequestEvent prUrl: http://192.168.200.23:7990/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests/9
2023-10-11 08:08:08,627 INFO  [moveworkforward-bitbucket-1] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" n.t.b.processor.AbstractProcessor sendEvents event type: PULL_REQUEST_OPENED
2023-10-11 08:08:08,628 INFO  [moveworkforward-bitbucket-1] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" n.t.b.processor.AbstractProcessor sendEvents getting configuration for repo: 203
2023-10-11 08:08:08,629 INFO  [moveworkforward-bitbucket-1] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" n.t.b.s.WebhookConfigurationService Always add project configurations: false
2023-10-11 08:08:08,629 INFO  [moveworkforward-bitbucket-1] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" n.t.b.s.WebhookConfigurationService Always add global configurations: false
2023-10-11 08:08:08,629 INFO  [moveworkforward-bitbucket-1] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" n.t.b.processor.AbstractProcessor sendEvents enabledWebHookConfigurations count: 0
2023-10-11 08:08:08,629 INFO  [moveworkforward-bitbucket-1] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" n.t.bitbucket.service.LicenseManager Plugin licensed.
2023-10-11 08:08:08,629 INFO  [moveworkforward-bitbucket-1] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" n.t.b.processor.AbstractProcessor isEventAccepted for event type: PULL_REQUEST_OPENED, and result is false, class : RepositoryRefsChangedProcessor
2023-10-11 08:08:08,629 INFO  [moveworkforward-bitbucket-1] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" n.t.bitbucket.service.LicenseManager Plugin licensed.
2023-10-11 08:08:08,629 INFO  [moveworkforward-bitbucket-1] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" n.t.b.processor.AbstractProcessor isEventAccepted for event type: PULL_REQUEST_OPENED, and result is false, class : BuildStatusSetProcessor
2023-10-11 08:08:08,629 INFO  [moveworkforward-bitbucket-1] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" n.t.b.p.ProjectRepositoryModificationProcessor Event PULL_REQUEST_OPENED accepted: false
2023-10-11 08:08:08,629 INFO  [moveworkforward-bitbucket-1] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" n.t.bitbucket.service.LicenseManager Plugin licensed.
2023-10-11 08:08:08,629 INFO  [moveworkforward-bitbucket-1] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3198x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "POST /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests HTTP/1.1" n.t.b.processor.AbstractProcessor isEventAccepted for event type: PULL_REQUEST_OPENED, and result is false, class : RepositoryMirrorSynchronizedProcessor
2023-10-11 08:08:09,302 DEBUG [http-nio-7990-exec-6] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3200x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "GET /projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests/9/overview HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.p.w.f.RequestCacheClientPageDataHandler Context bitbucket.web.repository.clone.dialog.options was required already. Ignoring.
2023-10-11 08:08:10,225 DEBUG [http-nio-7990-exec-7] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3205x1 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "GET /rest/client-plugins/1.0/client-plugins/items HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.i18n.PluginI18nService No values found in any valid locale for key  and locales [en_US, en]
2023-10-11 08:08:10,508 DEBUG [http-nio-7990-exec-2] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3211x0 hxbgmf 10.212.134.101 "GET /rest/api/latest/projects/JENKINS/repos/jenkins/pull-requests/9/activities HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.p.c.d.DriftCommentUpdateProcessor 203:9@0: No rescopes are pending drift
2023-10-11 08:08:10,512 DEBUG [http-nio-7990-exec-4] admin @Y7JMOKx488x3213x2 hx
```

Has anyone faced a similar issue or have suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin requires a secure connection.

i.e over port 443.

**Issuing a certificate to my Bitbucket server has solved this issue.**
[image]